# Getting error while building rpm - File not found by glob:

Tags: python, linux, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am building rpm on RHEL-6/64 bit server.

```
    # rpmbuild -bb extras/rpm/neatx.spec

    RPM build errors:
        File not found by glob: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/neatx-0.1-1.el6.x86_64/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/neatx/*
```

I do see the same files under `/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/neatx-0.1-1.el6.x86_64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` directory.

```
    # ls -l /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/neatx-0.1-1.el6.x86_64/usr/lib/    
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root bin 4096 Apr 19 14:45 python2.7

    # ls -l  /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/neatx-0.1-1.el6.x86_64/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root bin 4096 Apr 19 14:45 neatx
```

These are python related entries in `neatx.spec` file.

```
    # grep -i python   extras/rpm/neatx.spec
    %{!?python_sitelib: %global python_sitelib %(%{__python} -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()")}
    
    BuildRequires: python-devel
    
    BuildRequires: python-docutils
    
    Requires: python >= 2.4
    
    Requires: python-simplejson
    
    %python_sitelib/%{name}/*
```

Will appreciate your help/suggestions for fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance.
-Shashi Divekar

Comment: It looks like you have both python `2.6` and python `2.7` on your machine. Somehow the build system sees the `2.7` one, but the `spec` file is claiming `2.6`. I don't know offhand how to fix that tho, sorry.

Comment: Aaron, Thanks. Yes, I have  both python 2.6 and python 2.7. One is under /usr/local/bin and other is under /usr/bin. The default PATH is using python 2.7. I changed the PATH and made it to see python 2.6 first. After doing that "rpmbuild -bb extras/rpm/neatx.spec" worked fine. Will like to know how to make rpmbuild work using python 2.7. Thanks again!

Comment: You would have to package your 2.7 copy as a special RPM and then require that. Using non-system `python` is non-trivial and not for the faint of heart...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distributing a python package along with module dependencies using RPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109409/distributing-a-python-package-along-with-module-dependencies-using-rpm)

Answer (score 1):

The Command `rpmbuild` produces an Error because you are required to give a **List of installed Files** in your `.spec` File at:

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%python_sitelib/%{name}/*
```

And the Path `%python_sitelib` is resolved into

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

But in the `%install` Section of your `.spec` the Files have been placed into another Directory which is:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

You should use in your `%install` Section also the same Macro `%python_sitelib` as in the `%files` Section.